# Как удалить эмодзи из строки на python?

Tags: python, алгоритм, удаление, удаление-символов

Парсю объявление с домклика и попалось вот такое описание с эмодзи

```
text ="⚡️Квартира укомплектована... Отличный собственник ...Опиcание квартиры...Условия сдачи...Звоните и..."
```

Я использовал следующий алгоритм, который увидел на stackoverflow

```py
import re
def deEmojify(text):
    regrex_pattern = re.compile(pattern = "["
    u"\U0001F600-\U0001F64F"  # emoticons
    u"\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF"  # symbols & pictographs
    u"\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF"  # transport & map symbols
    u"\U0001F1E0-\U0001F1FF"  # flags (iOS)
                       "]+", flags = re.UNICODE)
    return regrex_pattern.sub(r'',text)
```

После отработки функции остаются вот эти эмодзи ⚡️

Вопрос, как избавиться от этого эмодзи ⚡️ и других, которые могут встретиться?

P.S. Еще не полностью разобрался в этой функции, что за 9-изначные коды и где их смотреть

Comment: Если не предполагается текст на не европейских языках, то я бы удалял все символы за пределами Basic Multilingual Plane, то есть все, код которых больше FFFF

Comment: Это не 9-и, а 8-значные коды с префиксом. Смотреть в стандарте Unicode или любой выдержки из него. Тут есть список диапазонов https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_(%D0%AE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4)

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Сейчас проверю

Answer (score 4):

Вопрос решил, благодаря [Герману Борисову](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/183614/%d0%93%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd-%d0%91%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2) за предоставленную информацию о Unicode! Ознакомившись с таблицей юникода, переписал функцию

```py
def deEmojify(text):
    regrex_pattern = re.compile(pattern = "["
                                u"\U00000000-\U00000009"
                                u"\U0000000B-\U0000001F"
                                u"\U00000080-\U00000400"
                                u"\U00000402-\U0000040F"
                                u"\U00000450-\U00000450"
                                u"\U00000452-\U0010FFFF"
                                "]+", flags = re.UNICODE)
    return regrex_pattern.sub(r'',text)
```

В `\U00000000-\U0000009` удаляются все знаки табуляции и т.д., кроме `\n`, потому что он мне нужен и его юникод `0000000A`

Затем `\U0000000B-\U0000001F` продолжаю дальше удалять все табуляции и прочее вещи. После 001F идет американская раскладка клавиатуры + спец символы + числа. Мне это нужно, я решил оставить.

Тут `\U00000080-\U00000400` я продолжаю удалять ненужные символы, которые могут встретиться. А после 00400 идет русская заглавная буква Ё. Мы русские порой забываем о ней и это нормально, но малая часть населения усердно ее пишут. Поэтому она нам нужна

Затем `\U00000402-\U0000040F` продолжаем удалять ненужные буквы из кириллицы.

Тут `\U00000450-\U00000450` удаляем принудительно символ перед маленькой буквой ё. Ничего умнее не придумал, поэтому решил написать так.

И как кончилась русская раскладка `\U00000452-\U0010FFFF` удаляю все остальные символы. Результат прекрасный

```py
print(deEmojify('⚡️Квартира укомплектована... Отличный собственник \n...Опиcание квартиры...Условия сдачи...Звоните и...'))
print(deEmojify('qwertyuiop[]'))
print(deEmojify('QWERTYUIOP{}|'))
print(deEmojify('asdfghjkl;\''))
print(deEmojify('ASDFGHJKL:"'))
print(deEmojify('zxcvbnm,./'))
print(deEmojify('ZXCVBNM<>?'))
print(deEmojify('Ёё1234567890'))
print(deEmojify('!@#$%^&*()-=+'))
print(deEmojify('!"№;%:?*()_+=\\/'))
print(deEmojify('йцукенгшщзхъ'))
print(deEmojify('ЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪ'))
print(deEmojify('фывапролджэ'))
print(deEmojify('ФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭ'))
print(deEmojify('ячсмитьбю.'))
print(deEmojify('ЯЧСМИТЬБЮ,'))
```

Результат

```
Квартира укомплектована... Отличный собственник 
...Опиcание квартиры...Условия сдачи...Звоните и...
qwertyuiop[]
QWERTYUIOP{}|
asdfghjkl;'
ASDFGHJKL:"
zxcvbnm,./
ZXCVBNM<>?
Ёё1234567890
!@#$%^&*()-=+
!";%:?*()_+=\/
йцукенгшщзхъ
ЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪ
фывапролджэ
ФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭ
ячсмитьбю.
ЯЧСМИТЬБЮ,
```